# i want to modify this like buy when candles breaks above or close > resistance and sell when candles break down or close < support

Tags: pine-script

The conditions are:

buy=close > support
sell=close < resistance
and the code.

//Plot Bar
plotshape(buy ? lowlel : na,title="Up", color=color.new(#00ff00,1), text="buy",location=location.belowbar, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small)
plotshape(sell ? highlel: na,title="Down",

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this

```
buy = ta.crossover(close, support)
sell = ta.crossunder(close, resistance)
```